# for loop returns columns filled with na values

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi i am trying to loop over multiple columns of a data.frame in R and update their value.

```
col <- c('LS', 'ST', 'RS', 'LW', 'LF', 'CF', 'RF', 'RW', 'LAM', 'CAM', 'RAM',
         'LM', 'LCM', 'CM', 'RCM', 'RM', 'LWB', 'LDM', 'CDM', 'RDM', 'RWB',
         'LB', 'LCB', 'CB', 'RCB', 'RB')

for(i in col){
  new = stri_extract_first_regex(df$i, "[0-9]+")
  df[,glue('new_{i}')] <- new
}
```

The regex expression is working but when i run the code it creates new columns as expected but filled with na values. I am missing something when indexing but don't know what.

Comment: It's easier, if you share a sample of `df` using `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: because you cannot have `df$i` you should use `df[[i]]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `dplyr`s `across` function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(col, ~stri_extract_first_regex(.x, "[0-9]+"), .names = "{.col}_new"))
```